# How to double the values in odd possitions on an array, and return the full array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I need to double the values of the odd possitions and return the doubled values and the untouched ones in a new array in the same order as they came. I already tried with indexOf() but when a number is repeated in the array it won't double and returns the same. I know I can use a "for", but I'm mostly looking for a direct simple way to keep my code short. I'm using vanilla Javascript.

```
let num="123456"
let numArray=Array.from(num)
```

Wanted output:

```
newArray[1,4,3,8,5,12]
```

Also, very new developer here...so, sorry if this went too long. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const newArray = Array.from("123456", (num, index) => { if(index % 2 === 1){ return num * 2; } return Number(num); });`. Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, or arrays](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: [..."123456"].map((e,i)=>i%2 ? 2*e : +e)